# Match numbers in different formats

Tags: javascript, regex, numbers, separator

- I have a regex for matching number written in English:
  `[1-9]\d{0,2}(,\d{1,3})+(\.\d+)?`
  For example, `buy a sport car 1,000,000.25` will match this regex.
- I also have a regex for matching number written in my language (Vietnamese - basically the `,` and `.` symbol are swapped)
  `[1-9]\d{0,2}(\.\d{1,3})+(,\d+)?`
  For example, `buy a sport car 1.000.000,25` will match this regex.
  This is what I want:

  1. If a number **match the English number regex**, it **shouldn't match the Vietnamese number regex**. However, in complicated case like this: `buy a house 1.234.532.727,94 in October` it matches both regexes.
  2. Given the case of the **English regex**, my current English regex couldn't match this string: `2.45 buy a song` .
  3. From this string: `buy a house 1.234.532.727,94 in October`, how can I extract this string: `1.234.532.727,94` ?

How should I correct my regexes to get what I want ?

Answer (score 1):

For the second part of your question, to make the English locale regex match `2.45` all you need to do is make the comma term `(,\d{1,3})` optional:

```
[1-9]\d{0,2}(,\d{1,3})*(\.\d+)?
                     ^^^ change + to *
```

For your first question, I think your separate regexes are already filtering out only the English or Vietnamese locales correctly, q.v. the two demos below.  The only thing I needed to do was to add anchors `^` and `$`.

## English




## Vietnamese

**Update:**

If you want to extract the English locale number from the following sentence:

```
buy books 12.45 at school
```

then you can try this code:

```
var regex = /.*(?:\s+|^)([1-9]\d{0,2}(?:,\d{1,3})*(?:\.\d+)?)(?:\s+|$).*/g;
var matches = regex.exec("buy books 12.45 at school");
console.log(matches[1]);
```

[**Demo**](http://rextester.com/ODLZQ33203)

Comment: Thanks! I've just updated my question. What if I want to match this sentence: `buy a sport car 1,000,000.25` in English ? Also, How can I extract this string `1,000,000.25` from the sentence above ?

Comment: Do you want to match that exact text or just any text in general?

Comment: any text in general, for example `buy books 12.45 at school`, I want to extract `12.45` from the sentence

Comment: @sonlexqt I made an update to address your new question.

Answer (score 1):

> If a number match the English number regex, it shouldn't match the
>   Vietnamese number regex

Use start `^` and end `$` for both regex, so

```
/^[1-9]\d{0,2}(,\d{1,3})+(\.\d+)?$/.test( "1.234.532.727,94" ) ; //false
```

> Given the case of the English regex, my current English regex couldn't
>   match this string: 2.45

This is because `(,\d{1,3})+` will require at least one 3 digit occurrence, make it `(,\d{1,3})*`

```
/^[1-9]\d{0,2}(,\d{1,3})*(\.\d+)?$/.test( "2.45" ); //true
```

**Edit**

As @RobG has pointed out below, if you want to take care of scenarios like `0,000.123` and `0.123` then replace initial `[1-9]\d{0,2}` with `\d{1,3}`

For Example

```
/^\d{1,3}(,\d{1,3})*(\.\d+)?$/.test( "0,000.123" ); //true

/^\d{1,3}(,\d{1,3})*(\.\d+)?$/.test( "0.123" );  //true
```

**Edit 2**

In case this has to be a part of String, then put a **word boundary** around the regex instead of start and end symbol.

```
/\b\d{1,3}(,\d{1,3})*(\.\d+)?\b/.test( "asd 0,000.123 sad" ); //true
```

`^` and `$` are replaced by `\b`

**Edit 3**

Use this approach

```js
var input = "buy a house 1.234.532.727,94";

var matches = input.split(" ").filter( function( item ) { return item.match( /(\d{1,3}(,\d{1,3})*(\.\d+)?)/g ) });

console.log( matches );
```

Comment: `^[1-9]\d{0,2}` should be `^\d{1,3}` otherwise numbers like 0.123 fail due to leading zero. Also, what to make of 0,000.123?

Comment: @gurvinder372 Thanks! I've just updated my question. What if I want to match this sentence: `buy a sport car 1,000,000.25` in English ? Also, How can I extract this string `1,000,000.25` from the sentence above ?

Comment: @gurvinder372 thanks ! Any suggestions on how to extract the number string ? For example `buy a house 1.234.532.727,94`, I want to get the number string `1.234.532.727,94`

Answer (score 1):

The best regex for that purpose will be

```
(?:^|\s)(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?)(?!\S)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xrsPSx/5).

The `(?:^|\s)` matches the start of string or a whitespace before the number and `(?!\S)` checks for the whitepsace or end of string after the number without consuming them.

JS demo:

```js
var rx = /(?:^|\s)(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?)(?!\S)/g;
var str = "buy a sport car 1,000,000.25 1.000.000,25 2,000,000.25 3,000,000.25 test 2.45 and reject test 2,45";
var res=[], m;

while (m = rx.exec(str)) {
    res.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! In your English regex demo (https://regex101.com/r/xrsPSx/1), How can I accept `test 2.45` and reject `test 2,45` ?

Comment: @sonlexqt Like this - [`(?:^|\s)(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?)(?!\S)`](https://regex101.com/r/xrsPSx/4)